# jQuery toggle class for two elements causes encounter

Tags: jquery

```
$(".header__link--theme").click(function(){ 
    $("body").toggleClass("posht--khakestari posht--sefid");
    $("body").toggleClass("posht--khakestari-tire posht--khakestari");
});
```

I have this code to change the class names of every element in the page, but the result is not what I except.

It should change every b to c, then change every a to b; but it changes every a to c. I tried to change the order of commands, but it didn't help.

**Edited**

I think my problem isn't the toggleClass, but is the way I select Elements. I want to select everything inside the body tag, then do something like:

```
if($('*').hasClass('posht--khakestari-tire')){
    $("*").toggleClass("posht--khakestari-tire posht--khakestari");
};
```

Comment: What classes are on the `body` initially?

Comment: In isolation the code works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/f3kgth8d/

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I used body to select it's children.

Comment: That doesn't really answer my question.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Sorry. `<body class="posht--khakestari-tire matn--sefid">`

Comment: The logic still works: https://jsfiddle.net/j3f87ta0/. Note that the second `toggleClass()` call does nothing as there is no `posht--khakestari-tire` class on the `body`

Comment: @Shahriar please check my answer and check first replace logic. it should work for you

Comment: Please show the HTML elements and how you have the classes initially as well as how you wish them to be in the end (second example perhaps).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to **replace** `class` you should use following syntax :

```
$(".header__link--theme").click(function(){ 
    $("body").attr('class').replace("posht--khakestari" , "posht--sefid");
    $("body").attr('class').replace("posht--khakestari-tire" , "posht--khakestari");
});
```

Otherwise You need to toggle each class one by one :

```
$(".header__link--theme").click(function(){ 
    $("body").toggleClass("posht--khakestari");
    $("body").toggleClass("posht--sefid");
    $("body").toggleClass("posht--khakestari-tire");
    $("body").toggleClass("posht--khakestari");
});
```

This will work for you.